# python reading csv is interfered by utf-8 coding

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I am trying to read csv file using pandas in python and later I am trying to read a text file and replacing content with values in csv 
I am getting below errors :

```
 lines = [line.decode('utf-8').strip() for line in lines]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 140: invalid start byte
```

Comment: try `chardet your_file.csv` in terminal to find what your file's encoding is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using below. It worked for me in a very simple way.

```
 str= str.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8')
```

in case you are reading a text file, then here your need to run through each element of the list, you can try something below

```
lines= open("file.text", "r")
lines = fileread.readlines()
lines = [line.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8') for line in lines]
```

Hope this helps...